# Detecting influence of one point in non-linear regression (drc package)

Tags: r, outliers

I fitted an asymptotic regression model to my data using the drc package in R.
the model was specified like this:

```
model<-drm(y~x,data=mydata,fct=AR.2())
```

now, I want to check how influential one extreme point is in determining my curve.

So I run another model just excluding that point like this:

```
model_out<-drm(y~x,data=mydata_out,fct=AR.2())
```

where `mydata_out` is the same dataset as `mydata` except the extreme point.

How should I compare the two models in R?

Graphically, it is quite evident the point under examination is not really influential, but I was looking for a more "formal" way to do that (something like an r-square, that I know doesn't work for non-linear regression).

[This paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2290635?uid=3737864&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21103664409437) seems to be helpful. Does anyone know of an R implementation of the methodology? Or any other way of detecting influential data points in nonlinear regression in R?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2290635?uid=3737864&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21103664409437

Comment: Yes I think It will be useful. However, does anyone know how to do it in R?

Comment: Ah, now you are not asking a *statistics* question, but a *programming* one. I'll flag the entry for migration to StackExchange and edit it accordingly.